# Javascript - OpenLayers: Merge/Union two lines

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, turfjs

I need to merge two overlapping lines into one in OpenLayers.

I could find only one option - *turf union*. But it returns multiLine feature without merging the actual lines. But if I pass polygons, it works fine. Looks like it does not support lines.

```
var union = turf.union(line1, line2);
```

For example - In the below image, I want to convert the line 1 and line 2 into a single line.
[image]

Is there any other way to merge lines? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new continuous linestring by combining by joining the two sets of coordinates, for example

```
var coordinates1 = linestring1.getCoodinates();
var coordinates2 = linestring2.getCoodinates();
var union = new LineString(coordinates1.concat(coordinates2));
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike. It works for continuous lines. But in my case they can be overlapping as well. I have updated the question properly now.

Comment: You could use `turf.lineSlice` to shorten the first line (starting at its own start point and ending at the start point of the second line) then combine the resulting corrdinates.